# Class helper breaks override of virtual method

Tags: class, delphi, overriding, virtual, helper

Consider the following Delphi console app:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TC1 = class
    procedure m; virtual;
  end;

  TC2 = class(TC1)
    procedure m; override;
  end;

  type THelper = class helper for TC1
    procedure m;
  end;

procedure TC1.m; begin WriteLn('C1') end;
procedure TC2.m; begin WriteLn('C2') end;
procedure THelper.m; begin inherited m end;

procedure p(c : TC1);
begin
  C.m
end;

begin
  var C := TC2.Create;
  p(c);
  ReadLn
end.
```

I would expect the existance of `THelper` not to change the inheritence and print "C2", but the program prints "C1" instead, thus the overriden `C2.m` is not called.

When commenting out `THelper` (and `THelper.m`), the program prints "C2" as expected.

Comment: This post reads more like a bug report than a Q&A question. The behavior you describe is expected and documented. If you don't like the behavior, you should contact Embarcadero directly.

Answer (score 3):

`THelper.m()` has precedence over `TC1.m()` in this example. This is expected and documented behavior:

[Class and Record Helpers (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi))

> The following code demonstrates the declaration of a class helper (record helpers behave in the same manner):
>
> ```
> type
>   TMyClass = class
>     procedure MyProc;
>     function  MyFunc: Integer;
>   end;
>
> ...
>
> procedure TMyClass.MyProc;
> var X: Integer;
> begin
>   X := MyFunc;
> end;
>
> function TMyClass.MyFunc: Integer;
> begin
>   ...
> end;
>
> ...
>
> type
>   TMyClassHelper = class helper for TMyClass
>     procedure HelloWorld;
>     function MyFunc: Integer;
>   end;
>
> ...
>
> procedure TMyClassHelper.HelloWorld;
> begin
>   Writeln(Self.ClassName); // Self refers to TMyClass type, not TMyClassHelper
> end;
>
> function TMyClassHelper.MyFunc: Integer;
> begin
>   ...
> end;
>
> ...
>
> var
>   X: TMyClass;
> begin
>   X := TMyClass.Create;
>   X.MyProc;    // Calls TMyClass.MyProc
>   X.HelloWorld; // Calls TMyClassHelper.HelloWorld
>   X.MyFunc;    // Calls TMyClassHelper.MyFunc
> ```
>
> Tip: Keep in mind, the class helper function `MyFunc` is called, because **the class helper takes precedence over the actual class type**.

That last emphasized part is why `p()` is calling `THelper.m()` instead of `TC1.m()`.

Since `THelper.m()` is calling `inherited m()`, which is a direct call to `TC1.m()`, no virtual method dispatch occurs, which is why `TC2.m()` does not get called at all, even though the `c` parameter of `p()` is pointing at a `TC2` object.

If you have `THelper.m()` call `Self.m()` instead of `inherited m()`, that will allow the compiler to invoke virtual method dispatch on `TC1.m()`, thus calling `TC2.m()`, since the `Self` pointer inside of `THelper` refers to `TC1`, not `THelper`.

Comment: That explains why the helper code is executed, but it misses to explain why the code from TC1 is called and not from TC2. You might want to extend your answer explaining how virtual methods are called (VMT) and how a specific class implementation can be called directly. In this case the inherited call in the helper directly goes to ´TC1.m´ skipping the VMT.

Comment: @UweRaabe use of a VMT is an implementation detail, I'm not going to go into detail about how VMT works, there is plenty of info about that elsewhere.  But I have updated my answer to include that virtual dispatch is not occurring in this example.